# How to keep the structure of the Tablix and Field names when there is no data to show

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

When the data set returns no data, the tablix column headers display, but I also need the detail rows to display with a blank or zero for all fields.  Adding an additional row to the tablix is not an option, as the textbox names on the additional row must be different within SSRS.  I am using this SSRS report as a data source to a PowerPivot model.  I do not want the PowerPivot model to break when it refreshes and no data exists yet.

I would like to avoid adding an empty row to the data set.  I would prefer a solution that can be implemented with in the SSRS report.